# DB Integration tests with Microsoft .NET

Tags: .net, database, integration-testing

Does anybody have experience in writing integration tests in .NET for a specific DB interface?

In concrete, I have a DB interface comprising four getter functions each of them returning a table with values. The returned contents differ depending on the passed parameters. I have to verify that some general criteria are applied on the returned data.

My questions are:

- What kind of testing framework should I use? Currently I'm planning to use MSTest.
- Are there some general rules or recomendations to follow when writting the tests?
- Do you know about any information sources I could use?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can structure your tests following the normal arrange, act and assert structure.

For each test you will first need to arrange the data that is in your database.
Then you will act on this data by calling the function you want to test and specify a set of parameters.

Then assert that the returned data matches the parameter set and all the other general criteria.

Make sure that you test both normal program flow (data is in place, all the parameters are valid) and unexpected scenarios (invalid parameters or invalid data in the data store).

You also need to make sure your database is in a consistent state for each test. This can easily be done by wrapping each test in a Transaction (you can use TestInitialize and TestCleanup for this to make this automatically happen behind the scenes).

Answer (score 0):

I think You can use xUnit for integration test, followed by your init and dispose segment. see the document below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-7.0